# Problems with recode in r

Tags: r

Using some example code:

```
df <- structure(list(DWFRSS1 = c("Always", "Sometimes", "Never", "Always", 
"Sometimes", "Sometimes", "Always", "Sometimes", "Never", "Often", 
"Always", "Sometimes", "Sometimes", "Always", "Always"), DWFRSS2 = c("Always", 
"Never", "Often", "Always", "Always", "Never", "Always", "Rarely", 
"Never", "Often", "Always", "Rarely", "Often", "Never", "Always"
), DWFRSS3 = c("Always", "Always", "Often", "Always", "Always", 
"Always", "Always", "Sometimes", "Rarely", "Often", "Always", 
"Often", "Always", "Always", "Always"), DWFRSS4 = c("Always", 
"Always", "Often", "Always", "Always", "Always", "Always", "Never", 
"Often", "Always", "Always", "Sometimes", "Often", "Sometimes", 
"Sometimes"), DWFYSS1 = c("Often", "Often", "Always", "Always", 
"Always", "Often", "Often", "Rarely", "Sometimes", "Often", "Never ", 
"Sometimes", "Sometimes", "Always", "Always"), DWFYSS2 = c("Often", 
"Always", "Always", "Always", "Always", "Always", "Sometimes", 
"Rarely", "Rarely", "Always", "Always", "Often", "Often", "Always", 
"Always"), DWFYSS3 = c("Often", "Often", "Always", "Always", 
"Always", "Often", "Never ", "Rarely", "Never ", "Always", "Always", 
"Often", "Often", "Always", "Always"), DWFYSS4 = c("Always", 
"Always", "Always", "Always", "Always", "Always", "Always", "Sometimes", 
"Often", "Always", "Always", "Often", "Always", "Always", "Always"
)), .Names = c("DWFRSS1", "DWFRSS2", "DWFRSS3", "DWFRSS4", "DWFYSS1", 
"DWFYSS2", "DWFYSS3", "DWFYSS4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
15L))
```

I am trying to recode the variables using the code detailed below:

```
library(car)
cols <- c("DWFRSS1","DWFRSS2","DWFRSS3","DWFRSS4",
       "DWFYSS1","DWFYSS2","DWFYSS3","DWFYSS4")
df[,cols]  <- sapply(df[, cols], FUN = function(x){
   recode(x, "'Never' =1; 'Rarely' =2; 'Sometimes' =3; 'Often' =4; 'Always' =5",
   as.numeric.result=TRUE)})
```

However, as you can see from the resulting dataframe, 'Never' is sometimes not coded.  From the text it looks like this is because there is an extra space ("Never ").  How could I get R to remove these spaces (if they exist) prior to running the recoding line?

Comment: How do you read your data in? In `read.table` there is a `strip.white` option that might help prevent this from happening. Also you can always inspect whitespace by quoting your output--for example, `print(df, quote = TRUE)`.

Comment: Have you considered having your data in a "long" format? It seems like that would make your life a bit easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your values are `"Never "`, rather than `"Never"`.  The space prevents matching.

You can strip spaces with, for example, `str_trim` from the `stringr` package.

Full solution as suggested by Ananda:

```
library(stringr)
as.data.frame(
  lapply(
    df, 
    function(x) 
    {
      recode(
        str_trim(x), 
        "'Never'=1; 'Rarely'=2; 'Sometimes'=3; 'Often'=4; 'Always'=5", 
        as.numeric.result = TRUE
      )
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: Perhaps you can edit this in: `library(stringr);
data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) 
  recode(str_trim(x), 
         "'Never'=1; 'Rarely'=2; 'Sometimes'=3; 'Often'=4; 'Always'=5", 
         as.numeric.result = TRUE)))`

Comment: Many thanks @Richie Cotton How do I add str_trim when I import my csv? I have been trying to add 'str_trim=TRUE to the end when I import my csv, but I get an error message Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : unused argument(s) (str_trim = TRUE))  How do I use str_trim appropriately?

Comment: @KT_1, you read my original comment incorrectly. It's `strip.white = TRUE`. `str_trim` is from the "stringr" package and not part of `read.table`.

Comment: Thanks @Ananda Mahto - for some reason strip.white = TRUE is not removing the white space.  Is there anyway to use str_trim on all my dataframe once it's imported? The code in your first comment is working...

Comment: @KT_1 Why not just follow a similar approach to what I suggested for all tables already read in?

Comment: @AnandaMahto - is that your comment starting with perhaps... My real dataframe is about 150 columns, how do I remove all the whitespace without having to input all my possible answers for each column?